# How to focus one modal dialog over another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I have two modal dialog winforms.

1, Application opens

2, Dialog1 is displayed

3, Dialog2 is displayed (but D1 visible on top, but without focus)

4, D1 is visible on top of D2 (achieved by using the 'Topmost' property on D1) but I am unable to click it!

**I want to have D1 focused or clickable.** Why is D1 only visible on top of D2 but not clickable without closing D2? And **how do I make it clickable?**

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what you mean, can you do a graphic implementation of you application forms? to better understand the situation

Comment: You need to post some code. But it sounds like you aren't understanding what "modal" means. Show D1 using `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`

Comment: If D2 is show by ShowDialog() then there is no way another form in that application can get focus. That is the whole point of ShowDialog().

Comment: This is very poor UI design, and can only lead to massive user frustration as your forms vie for control.  If multiple peer windows need to be presented, consider an MDI approach.  At minimum, stop using `ShowDialog()` and use `Show()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design - when a **modal** dialog opens it blocks all other dialogs. So the dialog opened last wins.

You should think about changing the using concept of your application.